# How can i crop a specific area of image using python

Tags: python-imaging-library, ocr, crop

I wanted to crop a specific area of images, the images uploaded are of different dimensions but all have these areas so i want a python script that can crop actually that part and make a new image.

I am uploading the original pics too and the pics after cropping too, the output I want to achieve actually.

[First original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiIf0.jpg)
[First cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiMY4.jpg)

[Sceond Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2duX.jpg)

[Second cropped Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5uvh.jpg)

Comment: I think you should go on another website like Fiverr, to ask someone to make it for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.